# How exactly works build promotion with GitFlow?

Tags: git, git-flow

I'm having a hard time understanding how exactly the concept of promoting builds (and their artifacts) works together with GitFlow. I'm in the process of working out a continuous integration/delivery workflow with Git, Jenkins and (as a new addition) Artifactory. This is what I have worked out so far:

- Build artifacts from the `develop` branch will automatically be pushed to a `dev` repo (if unit tests etc. pass) and therefore promoted to a `dev` status. Further promotions are not possible for these artifacts.
- Artifacts from `feature` branches don't get pushed or promoted at all.
- Artifacts from the `release` branch can also only be promoted to `dev` (or should I introduce a `release` repo?)
- As soon as `release` is merged into `master`, the new commit is tagged and Jenkins runs the full CI/CD pipeline. After unit tests and metrics (build stages which are run on all branches) the artifact is pushed to a `master` repo and promoted to `master`. Then the artifact is used for deployment to a staging environment, where final testing can be made (these tests can be automated in a full continuous deployment setup). If all tests are successful, the artifact will be pushed to a `prod` repo, deployed to production and promoted to `prod` status. If any stage until production fails, the tag belongs to a version, that never made it to production.

Is my understanding correct? I'm mostly confused about the master/release merging. Intuitively I would have said, that the binaries from `release` would undergo the most testing. However, GitFlow dictates that only commits on `master` get tagged (and I don't want to tag commits that technically did not produce the binaries which land in production). What if problems are found during the build of the commit on `master`? Is it "wrong" to have tags, which did not make it to production? Do I have to revert or undo the tag or even the merge commit?

It would be nice to hear other peoples approach to this build promotion + GitFlow thing. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are so many different branching models, and so many people with their own takes, that I don't think there is a definitive reference on what "GitFlow" means. (Please feel free to prove me wrong, I love to debate this sort of thing).

With that being said, I (personally) find these two references to be very helpful, complete, and compelling:

1. [Original NVIE blog post](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)
2. [DataShift breakdown](https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html)

---

**So, what?**

In my opinion, your first two points are correct and your last two points are wrong.

From a build promotion standpoint, all `release` and `hotfix` branches are eligible (and expected) to be deployed to your `test`/`staging` environment for final verification. From DataShift:

> The code in the release branch is deployed onto a suitable test environment, tested, and any problems are fixed directly in the release branch. This deploy -> test -> fix -> redeploy -> retest cycle continues until you’re happy that the release is good enough to release to customers.

Then once everything has been verified and you're ready to release:

> When the release is finished, the release branch is merged into master and into develop too, to make sure that any changes made in the release branch aren’t accidentally lost by new development.

Or, to summarize:

> The master branch tracks released code only. The only commits to master are merges from release branches and hotfix branches.

Here is where it gets tricky and different projects have different opinions: where does the `prod` artifact actually come from?

As I see it, you have two choices:

1. Re-use the artifact from `test`/`staging` that was built from the `release`/`hotfix` branch.
2. Re-build the artifact from the commit in `master`.

From a *code only* perspective, these are equivalent - the code in `master` exactly matches the code that was just built and deployed to `test`/`staging`. However, from a *build process* perspective things might be different - different environment variables, different keys, etc.

Furthermore, things can be complicated with how your team views `test` vs `staging`.

---

**So, what to do?**

With the caveat that this is just my opinion and the assumption that `staging` means "production mirror", I think the following is a sensible process:

- Feature branches are not deployed to a shared environment
- The `dev` environment (if present) is built/deployed from the `develop` branch
- The `test` environment is built/deployed from a `release` or `hotfix` branch
- The `staging` environment is built/deployed from a `release` or `hotfix` branch AFTER normal testing/fixing has completed. NOTE: You could indicate this with an `RC` tag, but that's a team process question.
- After `staging` verification is complete, the code is merged from `release`/`hotfix` to `master` and tagged with the release version.
- The `prod` environment is deployed with the approved and tested artifact from `staging`.

---

Final thoughts:

GitFlow is a great place to start, but you're ultimately going to customize it for your own needs. Don't be afraid to say "this is what works for our team" and do it your own way - just make sure it's written down so everyone understands how you're doing it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This helps a lot. As per your suggestion we will most likely start with deploying the artifacts from the `release` branch. Depending on how it works for us, we might make some adjustments to our workflow. Nevertheless, I still have one question: Taking your recommended approach, what happens to the artifacts build from the merge commit on the master? Do you push them to the Artifactory, or are they simply discarded after the build (because they aren't really needed)?

Comment: @AdrianKuper Frankly, I wouldn't even bother with a build from the commit in `master`. My justification is that this commit is only for "record keeping" and doesn't represent any actual work - which is true because there are no unique commits to `master`, so (code-wise) this is identical to the commit that was just tested and approved in `release`.
However if you do want a build (for whatever reason), I think it makes sense to just discard the artifacts - they're never going to be deployed or tested, so it seems misleading to keep them somewhere