# How would build promotion work with GitLab Flow?

Tags: git, gitlab, continuous-integration, devops, gitlab-ci

I am looking into adapting GitLab Flow and ditching Git Flow as the branching strategy my team uses, but am having a hard time understanding how build promotion/binary promotion would work when setting up my CI/CD Pipeline.

I have read an excellent answer on the same question regarding Git Flow, but I couldnt find a clear answer on how I should approach GitLab Flow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56670350/7410216

I have also read some articles explaining the main differences between the branching strategies themselves, but I am having trouble in translating this into a proper CI/CD strategy to pair it with.

This is what I have worked out so far for GitLab Flow:

- We will have a `develop` branch which will be used to branch new `feature`-branches from. Whenever a feature is developed and ready, it will be merged back into `develop` branch.
- We will have a dedicated environment called `test`: This environment will host the version of the code base as is currently stored in the `develop` branch. This environment will be mainly used to run some integration testing etc. This means that whenever a `feature`-branch is merged into  `develop` branch, this environment will be automatically (re)deployed.
  This is done by building a docker-image and deploying the container based on this image on a Kubernetes cluster.
- Next, when we want to release a new version, I am not sure what the best way is to push the new version of the application onto the pre-production (or staging/acceptance) environments and then towards the production environment itself. I'd say we make a branch called `release-x` and then work on that branch for any last-moment changes. The pre-production area would be deployed based on this branch (so a new image, say `image-x`, is built based on this branch). Then when we are done, `image-x` is pushed to production. But this doesnt seem to be GitLab Flow then, right? This is strongly resembling Git Flow itself, which the team is already using, and is described in the link above.

And this is where I get stuck. How should I now move forward with build promotion? Where would the key differences in setting up my CI/CD pipeline when comparing Git Flow to GitLab Flow?

Comment: With [this description of GitLab Flow](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/gitlab_flow.html) it seems the "Production branch with GitLab Flow" is pretty much the same as Git Flow except that you wouldn't test again on another env before releasing (so no release branch is needed). If you want  to test again on another env, and possibly even fix bugs, then you need a release branch, and that **is** Git Flow once again. Or, you could also use "Environment branches with GitLab flow", which I guess would be fast-forward merges which might be the only difference between that and Git Flow. cont...

Comment: However, that example mentions hotfix merges into Production, which need to be merged back down into the other branches just like in Git Flow so I'm missing the advantage the separate Env branches has over Git Flow unless you have more than 3 environments (develop/test, release/pre-prod, main/production). So maybe it would help to ask, why are you moving away from Git Flow in the first place? What problem are you trying to solve, which you hope will be solved by GitLab Flow?